# Run a query so that all values in any category that contains "Important" come first

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a whole bunch of rows. For simplicity, we'll say that each row belongs to categories A, B, C, or D. Those rows also have values of Important, Not important, or Boring. I want to sort such that if a category contains any value that is important, all values in that category come first, with the important rows first. It would look something like:

A - **Important**

A - **Important**

A - Not Important

C - **Important**

C - Boring

B - Boring

B - Boring

D - Not important

D - Boring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT my_table.* FROM my_table JOIN (
  SELECT   Category, SUM(Importance='Important') number_important
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY Category
) t USING (Category) ORDER BY t.number_important DESC, Category, Importance
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ccd7/2/0).

Comment: . . I think `order by t.number_important > 0` is sufficient for the question.

Comment: I don't know what 't.number_important' does.  Can you tell me what it's called so I can look it up?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: True, but the example shows Category `C` (with only 1 `Important` record) ordered after Category `A` (2 `Important` records), so I presumed perhaps that was an additional requirement not explicitly stated.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: It's nothing special - merely the alias given to the column in the derived table that is calculated from the expression `SUM(Importance='Important')` (which yields the number of `Important` records within each group).

Comment: No, as long as the categories with "Important" come first, there's no specific order among them.

Comment: It works!  Thank you!  Now I just have to figure out for myself what it's doing...